# Form input not showing on first page load

Tags: html, forms, gatsby, netlify

## Missing form input

My form input is not showing up on first page load! When I go to another page and come everything is resolved. And this is only an issue with netlify, when I deployed on surge, the problem disappears (problem also not apparent in development or bundle with gatsby serve).

I'm pretty sure this is because netlify adds unique code to make the forms work, dunno if this is the problem...

### These are the 2 deploys:

[x] netlify: https://vigilant-torvalds-72b098.netlify.com/

[x] surge: http://hallowed-sand.surge.sh/

I tried changing the form names, but to no avail.

Are there workarounds to this problem?

#### This is my code

This exact code works find with my other multi-page form (please see website). Also everything works find when I visit another page on the website.

```
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid"
import { FaMapMarkerAlt, FaTruck } from "react-icons/fa"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import { navigateTo } from "gatsby-link"

// Styles
import "./footer.scss"
import "../elements/subscribeForm.scss"

// Images
import nglogo from "../images/ng-logo.png"

// Form Helpers
function encode(data) {
  return Object.keys(data)
    .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
    .join("&")
}

export default class footer extends Component {
  state = {
    footerEmail: "",
    type: "email"
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      footerEmail: e.target.value,
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const form = e.target
    fetch("/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      body: encode({
        "form-name": "subscribeFormFooter",
        ...this.state,
      }),
    })
      .then(() => navigateTo(form.getAttribute("action")))
      .catch(error => alert(error))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <footer className="footer">
        <Grid container className="footer__item" spacing={32}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={5} lg={5} className="footer__item1">
            <h1>Be Future Ready</h1>
            <p>
              Our dedication to innovation and efficiency helps us provide our
              customers with long-term savings. <br />
              Subscribe to our newsletter to receive timely updates on products,
              services and global developments.
            </p>
            <form
              name="subscribeFormFooter"
              method="post"
              action="thankyou/"
              data-netlify="true"
              onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              className="subscribe__input"
            >
              <input
                type={this.state.type}
                name="footerEmail"
                placeholder="Email Address"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.footerEmail}
              />
              <button
                type="submit"
                disabled={!this.state.footerEmail}
                style={
                  !this.state.footerEmail
                    ? { backgroundColor: "#c8d6e5", cursor: "default" }
                    : {}
                }
              >
                Subscribe
              </button>
            </form>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={2} lg={2} className="footer__item2">
            <h2>Sitemap</h2>
            <ul>
              <Link to="/projects">
                <li>Projects</li>
              </Link>
              <Link to="/downloads">
                <li>Downloads</li>
              </Link>
              <Link to="quote">
                <li>Quote</li>
              </Link>
            </ul>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={2} lg={2} className="footer__item3">
            <h2>Connect</h2>
            <ul>
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/gundapowerpvt/" target="blank">
                <li>Facebook</li>
              </a>
              <a
                href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/14446246/"
                target="blank"
              >
                <li>LinkedIn</li>
              </a>
              <a href="mailto:info@gundapower.com" target="_top blank">
                <li>Email</li>
              </a>
            </ul>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={3} lg={3} className="footer__item4">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
            <h5>
              <FaMapMarkerAlt /> Administrative Office
            </h5>
            <p>123/10 Pannipitiya Road Battaramulla, Sri Lanka</p>
            <h5>
              <FaTruck /> Warehouse Location
            </h5>
            <p>184, Buthgamuwa Road Rajagiriya, Sri Lanka</p>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid
            item
            xs={12}
            sm={12}
            md={12}
            lg={12}
            className="footer__copyright"
          >
            © Copyright {new Date().getFullYear()} Gunda Power. All Rights
            Reserved.
            <a href="https://www.stem.lk" target="blank">
              Designed by Stem.lk
              <img className="footer__nglogo" src={nglogo} alt="nugoo" />
            </a>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </footer>
    )
  }
}
```

The input should show up but it just isn't. Working fine on development, bundle as well as surge deployment. So I think it's something to do with netlify's form handling boys. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a label fixed the issue!

Gosh.

```
<label htmlFor="newsletterEmail" style={{ display: "none" }}>
                  Email
                </label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  name="newsletterEmail"
                  placeholder="Email Address"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  value={this.state.newsletterEmail}
                />
```